# Ignore optional reactor-extra maven dependecies when running springboot app in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a Spring Boot app that i run in a docker container using docker-compose.
I recently added the reactor-extra dependency to my pom.xml and for some reason i can't start the container anymore.

Here's what i added to the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-extra</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now whenever i try to start the container i get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline (default-cli) on project backend: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64:jar:4.5.2 in central
```

The code works fine when i run it directly on intellij and there are apparently no dependency issues.

I took a look here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.addons/reactor-extra/3.4.2

and it seems that this "4.5.2" version of org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 does not exist. I assume this works on intellij because this is an optional dependency but the container building process fails when it tries to download that version.

I tried excluding it like so:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-extra</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But it's still trying to download it and i get the same error which causes the build to fail.

I also tried adding the existing 4.3 version of org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 to my pom but i still get the same result.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-extra</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

How can i prevent maven from trying to download that dependency?

Comment: Why do you use: `rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:go-offline`?

Comment: Actually i'm not sure, that was added to the Dockerfile by someone else before i got it

Comment: As you already excluded the eclipse dep I would bet the dependency is also existing somewhere else... try to  check via `mvn dependency:tree`...

Comment: When i run `mvn dependency:tree` that particular dependency is nowhere to be found.

Comment: But somehow running `mvn dependency:go-offline` fails because of that dependency. I tried `mvn dependency:go-offline -DexcludeArtifactIds=org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64` but that didn't work either

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by adding this to my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Source:

**go-offline fails when optional dependencies cannot be resolved**
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-690

"Running org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:go-offline against this project passes. With version 3.1.2 the goal fails with:"

```
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64:jar:4.5.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```